# Extreme case of K-interpolation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, interpolation-spaces, besov-spaces

Suppose $X_0$ and $X_1$ are Banach spaces living in a larger Banach space
$X$. The $K$-functional is defined for each $f\in X_0+X_1$ and $t>0$ as
$$K(f,t,X_0,X_1)=\inf\{\|f_0\|_{X_0}+t\|f_1\|_{X_1}:f=f_0+f_1\}.$$
Then you can define the space $(X_0,X_1)_{0,\infty}$ as the set of
functions $f\in X_0+X_1$ for which
$$\|f\|_{0,\infty}:=\sup_{t>0}K(f,t,X_0,X_1).$$
I was wondering when does this space coincides with $X_0$. Particularly I
was looking at the case when $X_0=L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $X_1=W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. This is
the Besov space $B^0_{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and I understand it can be proven
with Littlewood-Paley theory that $B^0_{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)=L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but I
would like to know if this can be proven from the theory of interpolation
of Banach spaces.

Comment: We always have $K(f,t,X_0,X_1) \le \lVert f \rVert_{X_0} + t \lVert 0 \rVert_{X_2}$. Thus, we see $\lVert f \rVert_{0, \infty} \le  \lVert f \rVert_{X_0}$, which implies one of the inclusions.   Assuming that $X_0 \subset X_1$ with norm-bounded inclusions, we have $$\lVert f \rVert_{0,\infty} \ge K(f,1,X_0,X_1) = \inf_{f_0+f_1=f} \lVert f _0\rVert_{X_0} +\lVert f_1 \rVert_{X_1} \ge C ( \lVert f_0 \rVert_{X_0} + \lVert f_1 \rVert_{X_0} ) \ge C\lVert f \rVert _{X_0}$$ for some $C \le 1$. Thus, if $X_0 \subset X_1$, your claim follows. The case $X_0 \not \subset X_1$ seems to be more complicated.

Comment: I messed up in the previous comment. It covers the case $\lVert g \rVert_{X_1} \ge C \lVert g \rVert_{X_0}$, which is the inclusion $X_1 \subset X_0$ and not, as I wrote before $X_0 \subset X_1$.